# Couldn't connect to firebase

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the phonegap-plugin-push in my cordova app to receive push notifiations from firebase:

```
PushNotification.init({
    android: {
        iconColor: "#ffb800",
        senderID: "725892xxxxxx"
    },
    ios: {
        "sound": true,
        "vibration": true,
        "badge": true
    },
    windows: {}
});
```

When I start the app I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to firebase
```

at the PushNotification.init statement.
Does anybody know what might cause this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by degrading the plugin to version 2.0.0 in the config.xml .